# Anyone know how to determine which color to use (white or black)

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am wondering if anyone knows how to look at a hex color and determine if the text on top of it should be white or black.

So if someone chooses some sort of shade of white the the text on top of it will be black. If black is chosen then white would be used. If yellow is chosen then black would be used.

Is there some sort of tell that I could look at a couple of the hex and figure out if the color will be dark or if it will be light?

The solution could be either C# or jquery/javascript. I am also using MVC not sure if that will make a difference or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a resource I found a little while ago, it has some really good info to start with:

http://particletree.com/notebook/calculating-color-contrast-for-legible-text/

Comment: interesting but I am sort of looking for a done solution. It is not a big part of what I need and I don't want to waste hours and hours trying to make it from scratch.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of any out-of-the-box solutions to your question.